# Can randbetween create multiple things at once?

Tags: excel

I typed this in a cell =VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,721),Players,1)

However it only gives me the position but not the corresponding player name and salary. How do I get randbetween to generate the whole row?

```
    Position   Name       Salary
      QB    Peyton Manning  10700
      QB    Aaron Rodgers   10100
      WR    Calvin Johnson  9500
      WR    A.J. Green  9500
      QB    Drew Brees  9200
      QB    Matthew Stafford    9100
      WR    Julio Jones 9100
      RB    Marshawn Lynch  9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `=RANDBETWEEN(1,721)` in its own cell, then refer to that cell from each column. Example formulae:

```
  A                   B                      C                      D   
1 =RANDBETWEEN(1,721) =VLOOKUP($A1,Players,1) =VLOOKUP($A1,Players,2) =VLOOKUP($A1,Players,3)
2 =RANDBETWEEN(1,721) =VLOOKUP($A2,Players,1) =VLOOKUP($A2,Players,2) =VLOOKUP($A2,Players,3)
```

Etc..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number being matched is in the first column of `Players` and the next 3 columns are the ones you want to pull from:

```
{=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,721),Players,{2,3,4},1)}
```

Entered across 3 cells as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)